# jquery with updatepanel is a boon?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have controls in `UpdatePanel` for which  I am trying to use `jquery` get the  maintained `state` from `hiddenfields` and rebind. Is it advice able to use `jquery` and `updatepanel` in tandem and hopefully not pull my hair out or is there a better way to than using jquery and `updatepanel` together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, my personal view is to go for `$.ajax()` but you can use `JQuery` and `UpdatePanel` together. For that you will have to use following as starting point instead of `$(document).ready`

```
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

prm.add_endRequest(function() {

});
```